# A Chwistmas Widdle With a Twist

Tags: riddle, mathematics, limerick

Chwistmas is the same with or without me, though I do wish you all Mewwy Chwistmas...

> I wish to be wid of my condition
>
> I am named and famed with humiliation
>
> A small happy square wheel! That's my goal
>
> And not mewely an empty hole,
>
> Gweeted and weceived with dewision

What am I, what do I want to become, and why?

**HINT 1:**

> W -> R

Comment: Is "squawe" a typo?

Comment: is that a joke? @WAF

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**CORRECT :) (Finally)**

Are you

> 0 ?

Do you want to be

> a small positive number >0

I wish to be wid of my condition,

> Nothing?

I am named and famed with humiliation

> You are something that means nothing

A small happy square wheel! That's my goal

> a small happy square **real**? Coz no matter how you square 0, you end up with 0! 
> Or you want to look like this? "□" (Irrelevant) 
> according to OP: a small **positive** (happy) real number

And not mewely an empty hole,

> ? It's a hole (0) 
> and according to OP: Zero is the smallest non-negative Whole number (empty hole)

Gweeted and weceived with dewision

> for being imaginary? (a dreamer?) 
> Zero is considered both real and imaginary, see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_number

Hint 1:

> W -> R and has implications of Whole Numbers -> Real Numbers (as suggested by OP in comment)

---

Note:

editing this as I came across [this comment from a mod on another user's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85372/you-sign-me-right-round/85391#comment248090_85391) stating that we should delete old attempts...

Comment: I think dewision is supposed to be [derision](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/derision)

Comment: @TheSimpliFire hoping to finish it before 2019, how's it now?

Comment: Finally yes!! Congrats for your continuing efforts :)

Comment: Wow, never would have gotten this. I was sure it would be some word where you can replace a W with an R to get a more positive word :P Nice job!

Comment: @jafe Sorry, just seen your comment! Hint 1 says `W -> R` and it has implications of Whole Numbers -> Real Numbers.... guess I should have said R+ but that might have given it away... :)

Answer (score 3):

Partial Answer -

What am I?

> An Irish beard

What is my goal

> to become a squirrel

Why?

> Because squirrels aren't empty? and they kind of look like beards?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not the answer. Good try though

Answer (score 3):

I believe this relates to

> Irish dances

You wish to be a

> Reel, used in square dancing

Because you are a

> Jig, which is the stereotypical Irish dance and and a tool used for holding other tools (which occupy the empty space or hole in the jig)

I'm unsure about the math tag, but I think the numbers

> 1, 49, or 100

Come into play since they are

> the smallest square happy real numbers ( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number )

Comment: good guess, but what about the math tag?

Comment: Edited in a weak guess!

Comment: Close, in parts, but no :P

Answer (score 3):

From HINT 1:

> W -> R

Ch(r)istmas is the same (r)ith or (r)ithout me, though I do (r)ish you all Me(rr)y Ch(r)istmas...

> I (r)ish to be (r)id of my condition
>  I am named and famed with humiliation
>  A small happy square (r)heel! That's my goal
>  And not me(r)ely an empty hole,
>  G(r)eeted and (r)eceived (r)ith de(r)ision

Resulting:

> 15 total w->(r)s converted: 7before spoiler, 8 w->(r)s in spoiler

Wordplay possible definition:

> [Irish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish): assumed to be Irish people, people of Irish ethnicity, people born in Ireland and people who hold Irish citizenship
>  [rish](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=rish): abbreviation for Irish and Celtic related peoples.
>  [rid](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rid): make someone or something free of (an unwanted person or thing)
>  [-(r)hell](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/words-that-end-in-rheel)
>  [rheel](http://www.rheelgroup.com/)
>  [merely](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/merely): just; only
>  [greeted](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/greeted): past simple and past participle of [greet](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/greet):to welcome someone with particular words or a particular action, ..
>  [received](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/received): generally accepted as being right or correct because it is based on authority..
>  [rith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rith): is a relay race organised in support of the Irish language.
>  [rith](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rith): From Middle English rīth (“a small stream”), from Old English rīþ (“a small stream”).
>  [derision](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/derision): contemptuous ridicule or mockery.

Repeated from spoiler and before spoiler:

> [rish](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=rish): abbreviation for Irish and Celtic related peoples.
>  **and**
>  [rith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rith): is a relay race organised in support of the Irish language.
>  [rith](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rith): From Middle English rīth (“a small stream”), from Old English rīþ (“a small stream”).

Additional note:

> I wish to be wid of my conditi**on**
>  I am named and famed with humiliati**on**
>  A small happy square wheel! That's my go**al**
>  And not mewely an empty ho**le**,
>  Gweeted and weceived with dewisi**on**

Resulting:

> 3 on -ending
>  1 al -ending
>  1 le -ending

Which ended up with:

> [onalle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oUHM0qCA2k4) an Indian song(?) :P

What am I, what do I want to become, and why?

> *My first guess* is you're an Irish who would like to be the one giving Christmas wish. Because whether you gave a wish or not it's all the same :P
>
>  *Second guess* that you're [Indian](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oUHM0qCA2k4) which don't want to continue being a dancer, named and famed with humiliation (with some praise). You would like to have a child (to play the wheel), don't want to be lonely and sad. Because you would be mocked if you dance until old :P

Comment: nice guess, but what about the math tag? +1

Comment: @OmegaKrypton not sure what to do at all about math tag :( best I could is getting M,O,S from the numbers.